# get PID of process started by Runtime.getRuntime().exec("");

Tags: java, windows, process, pid

I have this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("foo.exe");
```

and i want to get pid of this process.

note: There can be more running processes called `foo.exe`

system: windows

Comment: Try to parse the output of following command: `tasklist /v /fo csv | findstr /i "foo.exe"` - 2nd value in comma separated row is the PID of the process foo.exe. Also, beware in case of multiple instances of process!

Comment: That will work if there was only one process called foo.exe. but i want to get the exact one stored id var caled p